# Cannot use Mongodb distinct in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having a problem when I am trying to get all distinct values from a field("acc") in a collection

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var mongodb = mongojs('mongodb://localhost:27017/na');
var mongodb_data = mongodb.collection('data');


mongodb_data.distinct(
   "acc",
   (function(err, docs){
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        }
        if(docs){  
            console.log(docs);
        }
   })
);
```

When I run the code, it gave the error traces below

```
(node:45480) DeprecationWarning: sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
/.../node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                              ^
TypeError: cb is not a function
    at /U.../node_modules/mongojs/lib/collection.js:69:5
    at handleCallback (/.../node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:56)
    at /.../node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:313:5
    at /.../node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:455:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs/issues/61

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`distinct` method accept a `query` object as the second param, try this:

```
mongodb_data.distinct(
   "acc",
   {}, // query object
   (function(err, docs){
        if(err){
            return console.log(err);
        }
        if(docs){  
            console.log(docs);
        }
   })
);
```