# MongoDB get all distinct values

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

For my frontend I am using React and for backend Node.js with MongoDB.

So, I am trying to make a Select form (drop-down menu) to create a new object in MongoDB. For colors, you can choose between Yellow, Red, Green or add new.

How to get those values from MongoDB and render it in React? Should I use a different collection to store all the distinct values of colors or should I retrieve all objects from my database and get all the distinct values from there? Also, I need to do this not only with colors, but also with plastic types or manufacturers, for example.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method in your backend:

```
db.collection.distinct('colors')
db.collection.distinct('manufacturers')
```

and so on

Comment: I am a bit new to MongoDB. Where should I add this code? To make them accessible from my frontend via url of some kind.

Comment: In your application's backend, try to look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232542/cannot-use-mongodb-distinct-in-nodejs

Comment: Should I make a different route for this?